# Android Location Logging data structure

Tags: java, android, performance, data-structures, android-location

This is more of a data structure question. I am retrieving the longitude and latitude from my android device. Each location has a status associated with it. True for okay false for warning. If the device doesn't have an internet connection I add them to a queue. Values in the queue will all be pushed to a web server once a connection is reestablished. Now obviously server connections are slow so I don't want to add repeats to my queue if I don't have to so I check if I have logged the location before I add it to my queue. I did this by making a hashmap with the latitude as the key and a Location Object like this LocationData(double lat, double lng, boolean warning) as the value.

This is where I realized I messed up. Latitude is not guaranteed to be unique so if I were to use it as a key it would have to return another data structure for the value (I was thinking an arraylist of LocationData). The only other complication is that if it is determined a location does exist with a status of true and another one is logged at the same location with the status false then I  log the new value by just changing the status to false (warning > ok). Is there a better way to do this? My method seems overly bloated for such a task.

My Location class that keeps track of all logged locations

```
// Returns true if the location was already in the hashmap and doesn't need changed, otherwise
// updates/adds and returns false
protected boolean logLocation(String lat, double lng, boolean status){
    ArrayList<LocationData> latitudeArray = recents.get(lat);
    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat);
    LocationData locTemp = new LocationData(latitude, lng, status);
    if(latitudeArray != null) {
        int indexCheck = latitudeArray.indexOf(locTemp);
        if(indexCheck != -1){
            LocationData holder = latitudeArray.get(indexCheck);
            if((holder.getWarning() == true) && (locTemp.getWarning() == false)){
                holder.setWarning();
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            latitudeArray.add(locTemp);
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        ArrayList<LocationData> newLocArray = new ArrayList();
        newLocArray.add(locTemp);
        recents.put(lat, newLocArray);
        return false;
    }
}
```

LocationData class

```
public class LocationData implements Comparable{
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private boolean warning;

    public LocationData(double lat, double lng, boolean warn){
        this.latitude = lat;
        this.longitude = lng;
        this.warning = warn;
    }

    public double getLatitude(){
        return this.latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude(){
        return this.longitude;
    }

    public boolean getWarning(){
        return this.warning;
    }

    public void setWarning(){
        this.warning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        LocationData compare = (LocationData) obj;
        boolean equal = (latitude == compare.getLatitude()) && (longitude == compare.getLongitude());
        if(equal){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Not really important but this is the code snippet that uses the code

```
public static void handleWarnings(Context context, boolean flag) {
    OfflineQueue queue = OfflineQueue.getInstance();
    LocationSingleton single = LocationSingleton.getInstance();
    Location location = single.getLocation();
    ArrayList queueList = queue.determineQueue(flag);

    if (location != null) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();

        if (!StaticChecks.networkCheck(context)) {
            if (!single.logLocation(lat + "", lng, flag)) {
                queueList.add(location);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Location Logged and Added to Queue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Location Already Logged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            if (!single.logLocation(lat + "", lng, flag)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Longitude: " + lng + "\nLatitude: " + lat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Location Already Logged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }else{
        Log.e("STATIC", "There is no current Location Data in Update");
        Toast.makeText(context, "There is no current Location Data ....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize if there are any bugs in the code. I put this together to show proof of concept for the method I thought of. I haven't created tests cases yet.